# How to enable resize on JsPlumb widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jsplumb

Am building a list of widgets with JSPlumb and AngularJS, i need to enable resize using the handler on each widget. There is an [`example`](http://www.freedevelopertutorials.com/jsplumb-tutorial/examples/jsplumb-fully-draggable-resizable-elements-example/) already on it, i have implemented , but resize does not happen.
here is my code,

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="CustomWidgetCtrl"  plumb-item class="item"  resizeable>
```

**App.js:**

```
routerApp.directive('resizeable',function($compile){
return{
    restrict: 'A',
   link: function(scope, element, attrs){
         element.resizeable({
        resize : function(event, ui) {            
                jsPlumb.repaint(ui.helper);
            },
            handles: "all"
        });
    }
};
```

Here is the [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/wcTa47xMkIMz6FZEZ6sN)

Output after implementing pankajparkar's code,

[image]

**My actual widget:**

```
<div    ng-controller="CustomWidgetCtrl"  plumb-item class="item"    style="margin: 20px; top: 50px; left: 110px; height: 480px; width: 400px; " ng-repeat="widget in dashboard.widgets" ng-style="{ 'left':widget.sizeX, 'top':widget.sizeY }" data-identifier="{{widget.id}}" resizeable   >
```

Comment: @NaeemShaikh I modified the question with plunker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to move jQuery before angularjs.
Just wrap the element inside $, so that jQuery will understand that DOM and bind resizable event properly. Instead of link use compile if you are not dependent on scope and
Compile is comparatively faster than link.

**Directive code.**

```
 routerApp.directive('resizeable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function(element, attrs) {    
      $(element).resizable({
        resize: function(event, ui) {
          jsPlumb.repaint(ui.helper);
        },
        handles: "all"
      });
    }
  };
});
```

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5FVney1yEqgz293aVwV5?p=preview)

Hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: This is what i waned .now i can find the resize handler with my widget but it does not get resized. any idea?

Comment: @Sajeetharan  What is not resizing?

Comment: Have you checked the plunkr. div is re sizing properly.

Comment: yes it works well in plunkr , in my actual application nothing  happens when i resize with handler. any idear?

Comment: ok.that means the div is resizing but the JsPlumb chart is not resizing. Can you create a fiddle of same problem.so that i can figure out it whats going on there.

Comment: i added the code for the actual widget. is it because am setting the widht and height?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68565/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-sajeetharan).

Answer (score 1):

Two things seem to be wrong in your code.

First, you use `.resizeable()` but the function name is `.resizable()`.

Second, you use `element.resizable()` but `element` is a [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) object.  In your html you load AngularJS first, then jQuery; you should load jQuery first.

Here is the [updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dAe96gqKJ79VP4jYe1ZW).

Comment: cool, but the problem i have is i need to load angularJS first. is there any workaround?