# Enable resizing in dropped element -Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, jsplumb

I have a jsPlumb element that is being dropped onto the canvas and once it's dropped, the user should be able to resize it. I've tried having a css resize property placed on the dropped element but it is not being applied.

**CSS**

```
.partitiondrop {
    border: 1px solid #346789;
```

> ```
>    resize: both;
> ```

```
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 19px #aaa;
    ...
    opacity: 0.8;
    ...
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    ...
```

**Drop Function**

```
 var newAgent = $('<div>').attr('id', i).addClass('partitiondrop');
 dropPartition(newAgent, i, e);
```

**dropPartition Function**

```
function dropPartition(newAgent,i,e)
{
     $(droppedElement).draggable({containment: "container"});
     var finalElement =  newAgent;
     $(finalElement).resizable({
            resize : function(event, ui) {
            jsPlumb.repaint(ui.helper);
        },
        handles: "all"
    });


     finalElement.css({
         'top': e.pageY,
         'left': e.pageX
     });

     jsPlumb.draggable(finalElement, {
     containment: 'parent'
     });

     $('#container').append(finalElement);
}
```

Even the Resizable code within the JS function has no effect whatsoever

**Current Element**

[image: Current Element]

I would like for a resize option as shown below(without the scrolling- i.e. no overflow control needed) to appear on the right-bottom corner of the element

[image: resize]

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the CSS3 property: `resize: both;`.

It's currently not supported in Internet Explorer, as seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: I'm using Chrome and Firefox not IE & I've also included resize:both in my css section as shown above but it doesn't work

Comment: You're missing ``overflow: auto`` in order to work. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yqdzp7dk/

Comment: Thanks for the demo. I've added the overflow property and now the resizing icon appears on the element. But when I try to click and resize the element it it only dragged around as a whole and not resized. Could this be an issue from the element being draggable?

Comment: Since the element shown in the demo is  stagnant one it works perfectly. But the element in the context of this question is draggable

Comment: I cannot foresee any issues with two libraries used. There is probably the click-event catched completely on the div - including the browser events. A proper solution, for example, would be a draggable top-bar, like most Desktop UX, if you want to use your plugins in conjunction with resizable divs. 
Also there seems to be a builtin version in JSPlumb for that matter, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817367/how-to-enable-resize-on-jsplumb-widget

Comment: I have already included the resizable function as mentioned in the above example you provided but it wasn't working either. But this example is a really useful one. I'll try checking if I've missed out anything. THANKS a million

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the interact.js library as an alternative. Having the following method on the dropped element that needs to be resized the resizing function can be enabled through interact.js and the draggable function can be allowed via jsPlumb itself.

**Interact Resize Function**

```
interact('.partitiondrop')
    .draggable({
        onmove: window.dragMoveListener
    })
    .resizable({
        preserveAspectRatio: true,
        edges: { left: true, right: true, bottom: true, top: true }
    })
    .on('resizemove', function (event) {
        var target = event.target,
            x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0),
            y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0);

        // update the element's style
        target.style.width  = event.rect.width + 'px';
        target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px';

        // translate when resizing from top or left edges
        x += event.deltaRect.left;
        y += event.deltaRect.top;

        target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform =
            'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';

        target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
        target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
        target.textContent = Math.round(event.rect.width) + '×' + Math.round(event.rect.height);
    });
```

The interact.js file needs to be included as well. Further info on the [interact.js library](http://interactjs.io/) can be found here.